# Unable to build Perl module Net::MAC::Vendor

Tags: perl, cpan

I am unable to build Net::MAC::Vendor on a Mac w/ High Sierra. I am relatively new to Perl but have built modules in the past. The error appears to be:

```
Failed fetching [https://services13.ieee.org/RST/standards-ra-web/rest/assignments/download/?registry=MA-L&format=html&text=14-10-9F] HTTP status []
message [IO::Socket::SSL 2.009+ required for TLS support] at t/fetch_oui_from_custom.t line 21.
Could not fetch data from the IEEE! at t/fetch_oui_from_custom.t line 21.

    #   Failed test ''Got back array reference' isa 'ARRAY''
    #   at t/fetch_oui_from_custom.t line 23.
    #     'Got back array reference' isn't defined

    #   Failed test 'Fetched Apple's OUI entry'
    #   at t/fetch_oui_from_custom.t line 25.
    #                   ''
    #     doesn't match '(?^:Apple, Inc\.)'
    # Looks like you failed 2 tests of 2.
t/fetch_oui_from_custom.t .. 2/? 
#   Failed test 'fetch'
#   at t/fetch_oui_from_custom.t line 27.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /Users/johnprokopek/.cpan/build/Net-MAC-Vendor-1.265-13/blib/lib/Net/MAC/Vendor.pm line 320.
Failed fetching [http://standards.ieee.org/cgi-bin/ouisearch?14-10-9F] HTTP status []
```

Can someone help, thanks

Comment: *"IO::Socket::SSL 2.009+ required for TLS support"* : I tried to install this on macOS Catalina, perl version 5.28.2. Even if I first do `cpanm IO::Socket::SSL` one test for `Net::MAC::Vendor` still fails. I have to look more into this later

Answer (score 1):

I'm also still on High Sierra (10.13.6), on an ancient-but-still-running Mac Mini mid-2010.  Using the built-in `/usr/bin/perl` (v5.18.2), running `install Net::MAC::Vendor` inside the CPAN shell gave me the same error.  Running `force install Net::MAC::Vendor` worked, in that the module was installed.

A simple `perl -MNet::MAC::Vendor -e "print 'hi'"` works, so it looks like Perl can at least load that library, not really sure how to test that it works for real.  But, at least this will let you install it and try it.